# how do I authorize a request coming from a valid user of another application

Tags: java, authentication, spring-mvc

I have two web applications, app-A and app-B (both will be hosted on different servers). Now for a particular event in app-A, I need to call an URL to app-B so that app-B can do some processing. Inside app-A, I am following login/logout for authorizing users. So at app-A, everything is secure.

But if the URL is exposed to someone, they can play with my app-B. So how I can validate in app-B, that the request is coming from an authorized user of app-A ?

I am using Java (Spring MVC). Thanks in advance for your time.

UPDATE :

- app-A and app-B both will be hosted and exposed to public.
- app-A and app-B have different set of users (tables) in database and login mechanism.
- the scenario is with app-A the admin logs in, and does some activity. This fires a call to an unprotected url of app-B. Question is - how do I make sure in app-B that the call is coming form the admin of app-A only, not from any outside users.

Comment: Does app-B need to be publicly available to users of app-A, or can it be hidden behind a firewall?

Comment: app-B is publicly available. But it has a different user database.

Comment: I posted an answer but I just realised your question isn't clear - do you mean the request to app-B is from app-A, or is it from a _user_ of app-A?

Comment: let me clarify the question again. sorry for delay

Comment: OK you should definitely protect that URL, and make the admin login a 2nd time if necessary. Are you using form-based or digest authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You need single sign on server, like [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas/) is the good one .

Answer (score 0):

You have to create link that will have included specify request and, some custom text (for example: session id) and digital signature of this text signed with private key that will be shared for both your aplication. app-B can validate the signature, and if its pass, then fire the request.

[edit]: You have to remember that that passing token have to have limited live time, otherwise  if someone caught the link he will be able to use it later. So you can add to your 'custom text' (mentioned above) date and time of token creation and let app-B do not fire request that where created more than 5 min ago.